# 32 bit OS memory limitation on NUMA systems

Tags: linux, memory, 32bit, numa

Running 32 bit Rhel 6.5 with kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.i686 on a server with 46 Gb RAM and NUMA support.

```
CONFIG_X86_PAE=y
```

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz

OS is not able to see more than 14GB RAM and **lscpu** not showing any NUMA nodes in output.
 **numastat** complains system as not NUMA aware.

**config-2.6.32-431.el6.i686|grep -i numa**

```
CONFIG_X86_NUMAQ is not set
CONFIG_NUMA is not set
```

**free -lm**

```
              total       used     free       shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         14682        697      13985          0         89        408
Low:           242        230         12
High:        14439        466      13972
```

**numastat**

```
sysfs not mounted or system not NUMA aware: No such file or directory
```

**mount|grep sysfs**

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
```

- Can there be any limitation for 32 bit OS on NUMA systems?
- Why is OS not able to access 46 GB(2^36 > 46 Gb) even with PAE,is it because of NUMA disabled?

**On 64 bit its working fine.**

Answer (score 0):

**Can there be any limitation for 32 bit OS on NUMA systems?**

cat /boot/config-2.6.32-431.el6.i686|grep -i numa

```
CONFIG_X86_NUMAQ is not set

CONFIG_NUMA is not set
```

Kernel is not compiled with NUMA Enabled.

**Why is OS not able to access 46 GB(2^36 > 46 Gb) even with PAE,is it because of NUMA disabled?**

RHEL 6 32 bit doesn't come with Huge mem support

http://www.redhat.com/resourcelibrary/articles/articles-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-technology-capabilities-and-limits#note4